# UnicodeError Replacing Not Working - Python

Tags: python, string, csv, unicode

I am trying to replace nonunicode characters with an _ but this program despite compiling with no errors, does not solve the issue and I cannot determine why.

```
import csv
import unicodedata
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/pabbott/Desktop/Unicode.csv', sep = ',', 
index_col=False, converters={'ClinetEMail':str, 'ClientZip':str, 
'LocationZip':str, 'LicenseeName': str, 'LocationState':str, 
'AppointmentType':str, 'ClientCity':str, 'ClientState':str})

data = df
for row in data:
    for val in row:
        try:
            val.encode("utf-8")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            replace(val,"_")

data.to_csv('UnicodeExport.csv', sep=',', index=False, 
quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Comment: what is the error you receive?

Comment: Posting a dump of code is not a question.

Comment: I do not receive any error as the code compiles correctly though in the new file those nonunicode characters are not properly replaced by an _. I am wondering if it is a problem with the data.apply function?

Comment: This is the error I got before with the UnicodeCharacter - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 4: invalid start byte. This is the exact character -¤ and there are some more other than that.

Comment: I want this to be able to detect any nonunicode characters in a csv file and replace them with an underscore. Can somebody please help!

Comment: Or is it the for loop because for some reason it is only going through the first row rather than the entire file?

Answer (score 0):

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 4: invalid start byte
```

The above message (thrown from `pd.read_csv`) shows that the file is not saved in `utf-8`. You need to

- ***either*** save the file as `utf-8`,
- ***or*** read a file using proper encoding.

For instance (the latter variant), add `encoding='windows-1252'` to `df = pd.read_csv(…` as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/pabbott/Desktop/Unicode.csv', sep = ',', encoding='windows-1252',
 index_col=False, converters={'ClinetEMail':str, 'ClientZip':str, 
 'LocationZip':str, 'LicenseeName': str, 'LocationState':str, 
 'AppointmentType':str, 'ClientCity':str, 'ClientState':str})
```

Then, you can omit all the stuff <strike>`try: val.encode("utf-8")`</strike> in `for row in data: for val in row:` loops.

Read [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> `encoding` : `str`, default `None`
>
> Encoding to use for UTF when reading/writing (ex. `'utf-8'`). [List of
>   Python standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).